# Get innerHTML of DOM node using webEngine.executeScript()?

Tags: java, javascript, html, dom, javafx

I currently render a webpage using webEngine and want to execute a script on the rendered DOM tree, but something seems to be wrong. The output of the code below is

```
trying to execute script
script failed
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I realize I could do all of this with JSoup but later on I want to find the coordinates of rendered DOM elements using javascript. This seems like a good first step in trying to get there.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.net.URL;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class Extractor extends Application {
    URL anURL;
    Element p;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        URL anURL = new URL("http://www.gp.se/nyheter/varlden/1.2238540-frigivna-svenskar-landade-i-sverige");
        final WebView webView = new WebView();
        final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.load(anURL.toString());
        stage.setScene(new Scene(webView));
        stage.show();

        try {
            System.out.println("trying to execute script");
            String content = (String)webEngine.executeScript("document.getElementById('articleHeader').innerHTML()");
            System.out.println(content);
            System.out.println("script successful");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("script failed");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen to a special property to wait for `WebView` to load. Btw, `jQuery` object is available at this page:

```
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> ov, Worker.State t, Worker.State t1) {
        if (t1 == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
            try {
                System.out.println("trying to execute script");

                // fixed - innerHtml is a property, not a function
                String content = (String)webEngine.executeScript("document.getElementById('articleHeader').innerHTML");
                System.out.println(content);
                System.out.println("script successful");
            } catch (Exception e) {

                // you can also print the exception to diagnose the error
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("script failed");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @andrey! I'm new so I appreciate the advice. I have asked a follow up question that you might know the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091107/extract-dom-element-offset-using-webengine-executescript-on-headless-server